# Getting methods to work in a simple Java program

Tags: java, methods

I've got most of this program working apart from a few bits which aren't, I'm new to Java so it's not obvious what I'm meant to do.

Here are the methods:

```
public String getInventoryCode()
{
    return inventoryCode;
}

public int getQuantityInStock()
{
    return quantityInStock;
}

public int getDailyDemand()
{
    return dailyDemand;
}

public int getReOrder()
{
    return reOrder;
}

public int getLeadTime()  
{  
    return leadTime;
}

public int newDeliveryIn(int newDeli)
{
    quantityInStock += reOrder;

    return newDeli;
}
```

Here is the main code:

```
StockItem item_1  = new StockItem("A654Y", 1000, 50, 500, 13);

int quantityIn = item_1.getQuantityInStock();

for (int n = 1; n <=50 ; n++)
{
    quantityIn -= item_1.getDailyDemand();

    System.out.print(n + "\t");
    System.out.println(quantityIn);

    if (n % item_1.getLeadTime() == 1 ){

        System.out.println("Batch Ordered");
    }

    else if (n % item_1.getLeadTime() == 0){

        quantityIn += item_1.getReOrder();
        System.out.println("Batch Received"); 
    }    
}
```

It's a simple stock control program which counts days up to 50, each day reducing the amount of stock (quantityInStock) by X amount (dailyDemand) and then when it gets to a certain day (for instance every 10th day (haven't yet made a method for this, as not sure how to go about it) it will order more stock (reOrder) which will be delivered and added to the current stock after a certain amount of days after the order (leadTime). I think I'm almost there, just the last bit that I can't work out.

This is the output I'm getting at the moment:

```
 1  950
 Batch Ordered
 2  900
 3  850
 4  800
 5  750
 6  700
 7  650
 8  600
 9  550
 10 500
 11 450
 12 400
 13 350
 Batch Received
 14 800
 Batch Ordered
 15 750
 16 700
 17 650
 18 600
 19 550
 20 500
 21 450
 22 400
 23 350
 24 300
 25 250
 26 200
 Batch Received
 27 650
 Batch Ordered
 ...
```

I would also like "Batch Ordered, Batch Received" to go alongside the relevant day (3rd column) instead of under, but can't work out how.

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by printing to console after you have run through the two `if` statements determining weather or not to show `Batch Received` or `Batch Ordered`.

So change the `for` loop to this

```
for (int n = 1; n <=50 ; n++)
{
    String out = "";

    quantityIn -= item_1.getDailyDemand();

    out += n;
    out += " " + quantityIn;

    if (n % item_1.getLeadTime() == 1 ){

        out += " Batch Ordered";
    }

    else if (n % item_1.getLeadTime() == 0){

        quantityIn += item_1.getReOrder();
        out += " Batch Received";

    }
    
    System.out.println(out);

}
```

I just created a variable named `out`. I keep adding content to this variable and at the end of the for loop it prints `out`. This way you do not have to worry about printing to the console in any fancy ways.

## Update

Here is the solution for the stock problem.

```
int reOrderThreshold = 10;
StockItem item_1  = new StockItem("A654Y", 1000, 50, 500, 13);

int orderTravelTime = 0;
boolean orderInTravel = false;

for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
  //Do other things, like printing out daily demand and i
  if(orderInTravel && orderTravelTime < item_1.getLeadTime()){//If order has been ordered and has not arrived
    orderTravelTime ++;
  } else if(orderInTravel && orderTravelTime >= item_1.getLeadTime()){//If ordered and has arrived
    orderTravelTime = 0;
    orderInTravel = false;

    item_1.quantityInStock += item_1.getReOrder();
  }

  if(item_1.getQuantityInStock() < reOrderThreshold){//If stock gets to low, order
    orderInTravel = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. Do you have any idea how I would fix the issue I mentioned in the middle of the question? To summarise, I would like to set it to make an order on X day and then X days later the order will be delivered and add to the quantityIn.  Many thanks

Comment: @James Sure, how is "set it to make an order on X day" determined? When the item quantity gets bellow a number? Every 10 days?

Comment: Awesome thanks, I deleted my last comment to try and tag you but didn't work. Thanks again :)

Comment: @James NP, Let me know if it does not work. If it does please mark this as the accepted answer for people in the future.

Comment: I have just made a new question related to this if you are interested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263398/tidying-up-code-for-simple-java-program. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
System.out.print(quantityIn);
```

in the main code

Answer (score 0):

Before doing this:

```
System.out.println(quantityIn);
```

check if the batch is ordered or received afterwards! if so use

```
print(quantityIn)
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(quantityIn);
```